# Exact test for dependence of factors

Tags: r, dplyr

Given two factors, `X` and `Y`, where `Y` offers no information above and beyond `X`:

```
LETTER_PAIRS <- apply(combn(LETTERS, 2), MARGIN = 2, FUN = paste, collapse = "")
X <- as.factor(sample(LETTER_PAIRS, size = 1000, replace = TRUE))
Y <- as.factor(substr(X, start = 1, stop = 1))
```

The dependence of `Y` on `X` can be verified by cross-tabulating. Each value of `X` will be associated with no more than 1 unique value of `Y`:

```
tab <- table(X, Y)
stopifnot(all(rowSums(tab > 0) == 1))
```

... but is there a more efficient way?

Comment: It's fine to assume I have a data.frame `df <- data.frame(X, Y)`. How do I tell that column `Y` doesn't add anything if I know column `X`?

Comment: Usually I am accusing others of being obtuse, but this time it was me. I have found `table` and `rowSums` to be very fast in large operations, so I cannot think of a more efficient method. I will go back an delete my other comments.